# Can I have different max-height value based on user's browser?

Tags: php, javascript, css

how can I have the max-height based on user's browser?
I mean, when the user browses the page through firefox, the max-height must be 160.
On Chrome it should be 220.

I dont mind if I use multiple css files for this.

```
<div class="create_post_row clearfix" style="max-height: 160px; overflow: hidden;">
```

Thank you for your ideas and solutions.

Comment: Try [detecting the browser](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_browser.asp), then offering different supplying different classes. Or doing it entirely [server-side](http://chrisschuld.com/projects/browser-php-detecting-a-users-browser-from-php/) and supplying a unique style sheet for each browser.

Comment: Setting something like this per browser suggests that you are either misdiagnosing a bug or making some really bad assumptions about how much space browser toolbars are going to take up. Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for user agents and guess the size from there. If not, use javascript to get the user screen resolution and then resize the div.

Comment: It's not based on user's screen resolutions

Comment: Then get the user agent using $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

Comment: Can I implement IF statements on style "" than creating new css ?

Comment: Sure you can. Get the user agent first (switch or if/else) and create a variable with the size. Then use it in your HTML code, like that `style="max-height: <?= $customHeight; ?>`

Comment: Thank you Alberto. Just to know, what does the ?= stands for ?

Comment: I saw the tag 'php' in you question, so I supossed you had some php knowledge. Now I see I was wrong.

Comment: @Punkis: `<?= $something ?>` is equivalent to `<?php echo $something; ?>`.

Answer (score 1):

a js file I really like to use for this: http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/
its a browser selector. You can then just apply css styles to ".firefox #element" or ".safari #element"